# Toyota Corolla alarm system problems

Tags: toyota, corolla, security, computer, alarm

I just bought a Toyota Corolla 2013 Special Edition last week. Just after a few days, suddenly once I entered the key, turned and I was going to start the engine, everything started blinking, the monitor, and the security light, making flasher sound as if I turned flashers on. I then just drove, and suddenly a bit further while I was driving, it started honking by itself, looked like something makes it think I am robbing the car. After a while, the alarm randomly went off sometimes when I was pushing the lock button on the key fob, like someone pressing the panic button on my fob.

After a few starts and engine not starting, the battery also died. I went to the dealership, and they replaced the battery and said this should probably remove the problem.

What is the problem? Was it really because of a dying battery?! Should I expect the battery replacement fix the problem?

Comment: Gremlins ... just gremlins, I tell yah! :o) This would really suck! The only thing to really do is drive the car and see if it happens again. If it doesn't, chalk it up to the battery. I hope the battery does fix it (though I have my doubts), as it is a very weird issue.

Comment: Once the check engine light also turned on. Does a dead battery may cause engine light on?!

Comment: It depends, but I don't think it usually would. There should be a separate indicator for the battery/alternator.